# How can I delete a white space which appears after columns in React-Bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

So as a newbie I wanted to check if my new 'tool' will be working correctly. I set up a column at max width of website(12) and.. It is not really at max width, it leaves a white space right after column. (It used to leave white space before column as well but i deleted it with 'margin: 0', it doesnt work for the one appearing after column sadly).

Ive tried set up margin (margin:0) which worked only for white space before column, the one after still exists and i have tried to set up fluid for containter(fluid:true).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'

export class FrontImage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Container style={cstyle}>
                 <Row>
                   <Col xs={12} style={style1}>Column 1</Col>
                 </Row>
               </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const cstyle = {
    margin: "0px",
    padding: "0px",
    border: "0px"

}

const style1 = {
    backgroundColor: "green",
    width: "100%",
    float: "left",
    margin: "0px",
    fluid: true

}

export default FrontImage
```

I expected the column covering full width of window no matter what size it is (full-window/window/laptop' screen/else) but instead of it i get column at 12/20 of full-windowed website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in `bootstrap`, `container` `width` and `max-width` is set to some `px` like,

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    max-width: 720px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.container {
    max-width: 540px;
} 

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

If you want your `column` should take entire screen width, you have two options.

1. Avoid `<Container>` completly
2. Set `max-width:  100%` like,

```
const cstyle = {
  margin: "0px",
  padding: "0px",
  border: "0px",
  maxWidth: '100%'  //This will make your column to go with screen width
}
```